# Shared files between containers with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a project structure like the following

```
app/
   docker-compose.yml
   module1/
       Dockerfile
       module1.py
   module2/
       Dockerfile
       module2.py
   common/
       common_things.py
```

In my Dockerfile for module1 I have

```
COPY module1.py /app
COPY ../common /app/common
```

But Docker does not like this second line. Error is below

```
ERROR: Service 'module1' failed to build: COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../common ()
```

How do I tell Docker, through Dockerfile or Docker-compose, that it is okay for module1 to grab files from `../common`? I could symlink common so that module1 and module2 have common in their respective dirs but that feels like overkill...

Extra credit: What is best practice for sharing files across Docker containers? Perhaps there is another way that I am unaware of.

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context

Also this issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2745

Comment: If you need share files between containers, try using `-v` or `volumes` options to map host files/dir to your container. with volumes mapping, you don't need to rebuild your image whenever file changed. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a dependencies container and mount its volumes on other containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324081/making-a-dependencies-container-and-mount-its-volumes-on-other-containers)

Comment: This question is not about volumes as OP searches for a build-time solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by passing the entire app directory as build-context.

The `docker-compose.yml` would look like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  module1:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: module1/Dockerfile
...
```

The (first) `Dockerfile` would look like this:

```
...
COPY module1/module1.py /app
COPY common /app/common
...
```

**Some further comments:**

Normally you would publish common parts of your two docker images as a shared library. I'm not very familiar with python but I believe it would boil down to:

- publish your `common_things.py` as a python package on some python repository, so that it can be installed through `pip install`
- add a `requirements.txt` file in each of your Docker-images and refer to your python package inside it
- run `pip install -r requirements.txt` during your Docker-build to install your `common_things-package` in the docker-image.

However, this might be overkill for your usecase, so I think your solution for sharing the file might be the good choice for you.

Comment: Changing context was exactly what I needed. Thank you