# django static files are not copied to saticfiles folder on docker's container

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to understand what am I doing wrong when trying to copy my static/media folder to staticfiles/medialfiles on docker.

This is what I have:

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "mediafiles")
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV C_FORCE_ROOT true

RUN mkdir /www
WORKDIR /www
COPY . /www/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
RUN python3 /www/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

docker-compose

```
# use this file only for live production
# docker-compose up -d web
version: '3'
volumes:
  db_psql:
  postgis-data:
  esdata:

services:
  web:
    build: .
    restart: always
    container_name: django_web
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 LG__CXS4.wsgi
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    volumes:
      - .:/www
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - redis 

  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: "nginx" 
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./staticfiles:/static
      - ./mediafiles:/media
```

When I run my docker file I get: **5355 static files copied to '/www/staticfiles'.** but when I look into the container's staticfiles -it's empty.

Edit: see the ngnix config file in the answer below that clarify the mistake.

Comment: @eLRuLL yes - it's a must :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a dependencies container and mount its volumes on other containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324081/making-a-dependencies-container-and-mount-its-volumes-on-other-containers)

Comment: what about the current folder in the host? your working directory should contain the folders `staticfiles` and `mediafiles` with the static content inside

Comment: @adhg please let me know how it went so I can help you. Are you seeing those folders inside the host working directory?

Comment: @eLRuLL I'm still working on it, I figure the cause of the problem and now try to fix it. Per your question - yes, I can see the folders but they're empty

Comment: so this reduces the problem to just Django I would say. Good to know

Comment: @eLRuLL correction: the problem is with the docker-compose / dockerFile settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the suspects are neither the Dockerfile nor the docker-compose. The problem is with the **nginx**. It was missing the `www` in the alias.

what works is:

```
  server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  # serve static files
  location /static/ {
    alias /www/static/;
  }

  # serve media files
  location /media/ {
    alias /www/media/;
  }

  # pass requests for dynamic content to gunicorn
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://web:8080;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. if you are bringing up the containers via docker-compose you can remove

   RUN mkdir /www

   WORKDIR /www

   COPY . /www/

from your web Dockerfile since you're mounting the volume in the composer file

2. I would think you'd be trying to serve static files from your nginx container, so you'd `docker exec -it <nginx_container> bash` and making sure the files were copied to /static and /media there right?

Answer (score 0):

I change the value of the `STATIC_ROOT` variable by the address inside the container and not by the project address

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/webapp/static' #'./static' <-Both work
```

And then throw the next command in another command window, while the container was running

```
docker-compose exec name_service_web python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

Comment: It would be much more convenient to use relative paths.

<code>
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")


</code>